# How do I prevent users from accessing other users records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Expanding on the Zend Framework Album example how can I prevent users from editing others records?

I am using Zend Framework 2, PHP, MYSQL, and ZFC User Rbac.

Currently the 'album' number is displayed in the url.  If a user is logged in the table will show them their records (albums).  However if they go to edit an album it displays the unique album number in the url.  The user can then change this to edit others albums.  What is the best way to prevent this?  Also is their a way I can/should salt the record id before displaying it in the url?

Thank you for your time and input.

Matt

Comment: Do you currently keep track of what user's own which album?

Comment: I do.  There is a user_id on the Album Table

Comment: So when they go to view an album check if they own the album. If they don't redirect to them to a page giving them an error message.

Comment: The view works (let me know if posting code would be helpful).  I echo out all the albums owned by that user.  Next to each row is a link to edit the album (redirects to a different page).  On this page the url is www.mysite/album/3.  Once on this page the user can change the album number to whatever they would like.  For example the user could key in 1 and they would see the album_id of 1 to edit even though they are not the owner.  Would my best be be to run a query in the edit page to get the alum owner id?

Comment: So in the edit page logic do what I said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode to try and illustrate what I am talking about in the comments.

```
$albumId = /*however you retrieve parameters*/;
$album = /*however you get album*/
$user = /*however you get user*/

if ($album->getOwner()->getId() != $user->getId()) {
    //redirect to another page with an error message
}
```

Comment: You can also consider the use of Assertions, like in [this example](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/07.%20Cookbook.md#a-real-world-application-part-2---only-delete-your-own-posts)